# How to get the right rank searching in Google page

Tags: robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework (RF) to search a keyword relating to my website to know/find the ranking position of my web site in Google search page (ranking : 1st, 2nd,... and which page? 1st page, 2nd page ?).

Here are my code:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Rank
    Open Browser    http://www.google.com.vn    gc
    Input Text      name=q                   atdd framework
    Submit Form     xpath=//form[@action='/search']
    Wait Until Element Is Visible       xpath=//div[@class='srg']/li[@class='g']
    ${xpa-count}=    Get Matching Xpath Count    xpath=//div[@class='srg']/li[@class='g']
    ${lis}=    Create List
    : FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    ${xpa-count} + 1    # XPath indexes are 1-based, but Python is 0-based
    \    ${li}=    Get Text    xpath=//div[@class='srg']/li[@class='g'][${i}]
    \    Append To List    ${lis}    ${li}
    \    Log    ${li}
    Log List    ${lis}
    List Should Contain Value    ${lis}    robotframework.org/
    ${rank}=    Get Index From List    ${lis}    robotframework.org/
    ${rank}=    Evaluate    unicode(${rank} + 1)    # increment to get back to 1-based index
    Log     ${rank}
    Log    robotframework.org has rank ${rank}
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```

But on the ranking position on RF's log doesn't match to Google screen:

```
Documentation:  
Logs the length and contents of the `list` using given `level`.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20140509 10:25:51.025 / 20140509 10:25:51.026 / 00:00:00.001
10:25:51.026    INFO    List length is 10 and it contains following items:
0: atdd-with-robot-framework - Google Code
code.google.com/p/atdd-with-robot-framework/ - Dịch trang này
This project is a demonstration on how to use Acceptance Test Driven Development (ATDD, a.k.a. Specification by Example) process with Robot Framework.
1: ATDDWithRobotFrameworkArticle - Google Code
code.google.com/.../robotframework/.../ATDDWithRobot...
Dịch trang này
21-11-2010 - Acceptance Test-Driven Development with Robot Framework article by Craig Larman ... See also ATDD With Robot Framework demo project.
2: tdd - ATDD versus BDD and the proper use of a framework ...
stackoverflow.com/.../atdd-versus-bdd-and-the-proper-us...
Dịch trang này
29-07-2010 - The Quick Answer. One very important point to bring up is that there are two flavors of Behavior Driven Development. The two flavors are xBehave ...
3: ATDD Using Robot Framework - SlideShare
www.slideshare.net/.../atdd-using-robot-framework
Dịch trang này
23-11-2011 - A brief introduction to Acceptance Test Driven Development and Robot Framework.
4: [PDF]
acceptance test-driven development with robot framework
wiki.robotframework.googlecode.com/.../ATDD_with_Ro...
Dịch trang này
WITH ROBOT FRAMEWORK by Craig Larman and Bas Vodde. Version 1.1. Acceptance test-driven development is an essential practice applied by suc-.
5: Robot Framework
robotframework.org/
Dịch trang này
Robot Framework is a generic test automation framework for acceptance testing and acceptance test-driven development (ATDD). It has easy-to-use tabular test ...
6: Robot Framework - Google Code
https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/
Dịch trang này
Robot Framework is a generic test automation framework for acceptance testing and acceptance test-driven development (ATDD). It has easy-to-use tabular test ...
7: Selenium 2 and Thucydides for ATDD | JavaWorld
www.javaworld.com/.../111018-thucydides-for-atdd.html
Dịch trang này
18-10-2011 - Find out how Thucydides extends and rethinks ATDD. ... In this article I introduce Thucydides, an open source ATDD framework built on top of ...
8: ATDD | Assert Selenium
assertselenium.com/category/atdd/
Dịch trang này
24-01-2013 - Thucydides In this article I introduce Thucydides, an open source ATDD framework built on top of Selenium 2. Introducing Thucydides ...
9: (ATDD) with Robot Framework - XP2011
xp2011.org/content.apthisId=180&contentId=179
Dịch trang này
Acceptance Test Driven Development (ATDD) with Robot Framework. Executable requirements neatly combine two important XP practices: user stories and ...
```

Please take a look at the 6th position is Stackoverflow, but on Google is 5th.

And one more question, how to extend my test case if my website doesn't exist in 1st page, and then i'll search on next page and then get the page ID ?

Thanks.

Comment: You say stackoverflow is 6th, but looking at your logs I only see a SO reference in the 2nd item. Are you sure you're showing us the right data to match your question?

Answer (score 0):

The results on the page could be different between when you test and when you visually inspect. The first step would be to use the seleneium [Get Source](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Source) keyword to dump the HTML of the page. You can then use that to verify whether your code is working properly or not.

To extend your test case, I would start by writing a keyword named "get result" that returns the result, and the ranking. I would write another keyword named "next page" which goes to the next page of results. Then I would write another keyword called "find page with result" that calls "get result" in a loop. In the body of the loop I would call "get result". If the result isn't found, call "Next page" and loop again. Eventually this keyword will find the page with the results.